# echo \x6e in shell, but called from c++, using variable

Tags: c++, bash, debian

I am trying to output a hex value using a variable for the number. Here is an example of it with no var.

```
system("echo '\x6e'");
//output:
//n
```

Perfect.

But this doesn't work:

```
for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {
  system(("echo '\x"+to_string(i)+"e'").c_str());
}

//Which does not even compile. 
//compiler:
//error: \x used with no following hex digits
```

Well if you actually let the code run there would BE hex digits. I try \\x but then it just literally prints \x1e etc.

Comment: In the first example, the `\x6e` is treated as a single byte at compile time.  In the second example, the concatenation happens at run time, which is long after-the-fact of the compile time interpretation.

Comment: `system((std::string("echo '") + char(i*16+0xe) + '\'').c_str());` . I don't know what this is supposed to do, but this is the equivalent of the first call.

Comment: You're in a language fully capable of manipulating bytes. You don't need to lean on the `\x` notation which is a convenience for humans.

Comment: @Eljay I thought it submitted the echo statement inside of system() in one go. Is it possible though? To prepare an entire system() string then run that through?

Comment: `'\x6e'` is literally just the number 110 – 6e in hexadecimal – as a `char`.
.

Comment: @tadman your first sentence gives me peace of mind and hope. Your second sentence reminds me that I know nothing. But I think you gave me some ideas of what to google.

Comment: `\x##` and other escape sequences are handled very early on in compilation, while lexing tokens (e.g., figuring out that `"\x24"` is a string literal). Once the compiler has read this small piece of code as a string literal, your opportunity to use escape sequences is gone forever, with one very specific "exception" that isn't relevant here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Igor, this works, but you saying you don't know why makes me think you checked a resource.. could you possibly link me to that resource? :)

Comment: @chris very cool. Can I force a concatenations of variables in its whole to be read as a string literal? Like a+b+c+d where each variable were \x6e respectively.

Comment: @ED818, Almost, once each string has its final set of characters (bytes really), you can manipulate them how you see fit. The result can't be a string literal unless each piece is a string literal, but it can be something that works in the same places a string literal does, e.g., as in the answer.

Comment: @chris bah u guys are so dope. I've been learning from so for over a decade and this is the first time I ever had to post a question myself. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment explains the issue. Possible solution

```
system(("echo '"s + static_cast<char>(i * 16 + 0xe) + "'").c_str());
```

Comment: You can always use [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) to append specific bytes.

Comment: @tadman honestly my fault for copy and pasting, good catch, it works. The perils of being on mobile! -- and push_back() is very cool, thanks for that